# Why we need to save pytorch models with .net extension?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm a new learner for Pytorch and I am working on a Character_Level_LSTM_Exercise.

Why they save the model with .net extension in the model name?

I'm searching for the explanation but I didn't get any good explanation.

```
# change the name, for saving multiple files
model_name = 'rnn_x_epoch.net'

checkpoint = {'n_hidden': net.n_hidden,
              'n_layers': net.n_layers,
              'state_dict': net.state_dict(),
              'tokens': net.chars}

with open(model_name, 'wb') as f:
    torch.save(checkpoint, f)
```

Comment: It's a binary file, you can save it with the name you prefer. `net` probably relates to `network`.

Comment: Reading [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html#), `.pt` should be the favorite extension. But again, the extension doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever extension you like! Just make sure to be consistent.

The docu recommends to use .pt extension.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html

For more explanation and more extensions options see [Soumith Chintala's](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14864#issuecomment-477195843)
 comment.